# Javascript Number Representation

Tags: javascript, computer-science, number-formatting

It's a famous example that in javascript console logging 0.1 + 0.2 yields

```
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004
```

The typical explanation for this is that it happens because of the way javascript represents numbers. 
I have 2 questions on that :

1)Why does javascript decide how to represent numbers - isn't it the "environment" (whatever it is compiling the code , be it the browser or something else?) job to decide how it wants to represent numbers?

2)Why is it impossible to fix this behavior to match most programming languages(java , c++ etc) . I mean - if this behavior isn't really good (and most would agree it isn't) , why is it impossible to fix . (Douglas Crockford showed other javascript flaws , for example weird behavior with 'this' , and it's been that way for 20 years .) . What is preventing javascript to fix these mistakes?

Comment: I'm failing to see the reason for downvoting this question. I mean, I guess maybe there's a *bit* of rant in it, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does javascript decide how to represent numbers - isn't it the "environment"

That would be chaos. By having JavaScript define the behavior of its fundamental types, we can rely on them behaving in that way across environments.

Okay, "chaos" is rather strong. I believe C never defined what `float` and `double` actually were other than some range limits, and it would be fair to say that C was and arguably is wildly successful, "chaos" and all. Still, the modern trend is to nail things down a bit more.

> Why is it impossible to fix this behavior to match most programming languages(java , c++ etc)

This **is** the behavior of most modern programming languages. Most modern programming languages use [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) single- (often "`float`") and double- (often "`double`") precision floating point numbers:

- JavaScript: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19

  > **Number value**
  >
  > primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value
- Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

  > The floating-point types are `float` and `double`, which are conceptually associated with the single-precision 32-bit and double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values and operations as specified in IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, ANSI/IEEE Standard 754-1985 (IEEE, New York).
- C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691146(v=vs.71).aspx

  > C# supports two floating point types: `float` and `double`. The `float` and `double` types are represented using the 32-bit single-precision and 64-bit double-precision IEEE 754 formats

Comment: long time since I've touched java : you're absolutely right it behaves the same . However that still doesn't answer why the other flaws are left for 20 years ...

Comment: @Joel_Blum The flaws you mention are petty and trivial, bigger problems should be fixed first. Although next version will have arrow functions which have lexical `this`.

Comment: @Joel_Blum: Many of things that Crockford calls "flaws" are not flaws; they're just things that don't work the way *Crockford* thinks they should. In some cases, a lot of people agree with him; in other cases, they don't. If you look at the 5th edition spec and the upcoming 6th edition spec, you'll see that there are a lot of very smart people improving JavaScript -- including taking some of Crockford's suggestions onboard. JavaScript is an almost uniquely difficult language to enhance, because there are so many implementations of it, and so many conflicting stakeholders.

Comment: @Joel_Blum: About "conflicting stakeholders": After the 1999 spec finally came out, there were years of in-fighting and disagreement amongst the biggest stakeholders in the language. Brendan Eich *finally* managed to break that deadlock after a period of years, but it was not easy, and to do it required leaving a lot of things out of the 5th edition because the stakeholders couldn't agree on them. He and Mozilla could have just said: "This is it, you're stuck with it." But that almost certainly would have fractured things in a hugely counter-productive way.